# How is a function applied to data in PineScript?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to convert the following PineScript indicator to Python but i'm having troubles understanding how is the function applied to `src`.
The function `wpnr` returns a single value, which i assume is the value of the indicator on every candle. But how can it returns a different value if the function is provided always the same data with `src`?

```
//@version=4
study('Weighted percentile nearest rank', 'WPNR', true, resolution='', resolution_gaps=true)
//by gorx1 & wallneradam

multisort(base_array, second_array, reverse) => //[
    n           = array.size(base_array)
    index_array = array.new_int(n)
    
    if n > 0
        for i = 0 to n - 1
            array.set(index_array, i, i)
        
        n -= 1
        
        for i = 0 to n > 0 ? n - 1 : na
            for j = 0 to n - i - 1
                t  = array.get(base_array, j) 
                t1 = array.get(base_array, j + 1) 
                    
                if (reverse ? t < t1 : t > t1)
                    array.set(base_array, j, t1)
                    array.set(base_array, j + 1, t)
                    
                    _t = array.get(second_array, j)
                    array.set(second_array, j, array.get(second_array, j + 1))
                    array.set(second_array, j + 1, _t)
                    
                    _ti = array.get(index_array, j)
                    array.set(index_array, j, array.get(index_array, j + 1))
                    array.set(index_array, j + 1, _ti)
    
    index_array //]

wpnr(src, len, n) => //[
    data    = array.new_float()
    weights = array.new_float()
    
    for i = 0 to len - 1
        array.push(data   , src[i] )
        array.push(weights, len - i) //the actual linear weights
        // array.push(weights, 1      ) //unit weights, if u wanna do a raincheck
    
    multisort(data, weights, false)
    
    sum         = 0.0
    weights_cum = array.new_float()
    
    for i = 0 to len - 1
        sum := sum + array.get(weights, i)
        array.push(weights_cum, sum)
    
    wpnr  = 0.0
    thres = array.sum(weights) / 100 * n

    for i = 0 to len - 1
        if array.get(weights_cum, i) >= thres
            wpnr := array.get(data, i)
            break
    
    wpnr //]

src = input(close, 'Source')
len = input(50   , 'Length')
n   = input(50   , '%'     )

out = wpnr(src, len, n)

plot(out, 'WPNR', color.rgb(255, 255, 255))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

src is the close value = the value of the close of each past bar AND the actual value of the real-time bar.
On **past** candle :

- pinescript code is played only at the close of the candle.
  **wpnr** will be called one time only, with the close value of the bar.

On **real time** candle :

- Each time the value or volume of the real-time bar change, the pinescript plays again.
- So you function **wpnr** will return different values, as it will be called each time the value of the bar change.

Comment: I don't understand how it works on past candle. Does is it mean that wpnr on every candle receives only the current close and previous close?

Comment: wpnr returns only a single value, it doesn't return an array

Comment: @JayK23 I completed my answer, hope it helps